# Is editing a link using inspect element a valid XSS attack?

Tags: web-application, xss, attacks, vulnerability

Using inspect element, I can edit a link  opens a popup in edge with the text "1".  Is it a possible XSS attack?

Comment: It's not an XSS at all, tho an attacker calling a victim and telling them to open up developer tool and type in stuff happens. That's why Firefox requires the user to type a disclaimer in it before starting using dev tools (and that's why Discord Desktop App shows a `Stop, don't type stuff in there!` when opening up console with F12).

Comment: By definition, this is not a XSS. You are writing code to display in your browser.

Answer (score 9):

This is not a **cross-site** script (XSS) attack. This is you editing the page inside your own browser to attack yourself. You can try to write down and publish the necessary instructions how each victim can attack itself but this is not **cross-site** and not even a real attack. This is more like telling someone how he can shoot himself.

Comment: @VishwaRatna It needs to work for **other people** as well. If you are able to send me a link, and I click on it and it results in **your** JS executing in **my** browser, then it's XSS.

Comment: @MechMK1 , that's make the point clear. Thanks.

Comment: I think it's referred to as "self-XSS" in many bug bounty programs in the list of things that aren't reportable.

Comment: @multithr3at3d that's not a self xss neither. A self xss is when you are able to get a persistant xss somewhere only you can see when logged.